# How to create a sprint in JIRA with some time already spent?

Tags: jira, scrum, sprint

I've tried to create a sprint in JIRA with an issue that has some Time Spent already logged.
I have set the start date of the sprint so that it should cover the period when that time was logged. However, no Time Spent is registered in the sprint. Does it mean it is impossible to create a sprint that has some time already logged at the beggining?

UPDATE: The main goal here is to have a burndown chart showing the actual history of the work logged also before creating the sprint.

Comment: Could you just delete and then recreate the sprint, and then just log time to the associated tickets after the sprint has been recreated?

Comment: But then I would double time spent for each of the issues (the time spent before creating the sprint and then the same time associated after creating the sprint).

Comment: What's more I would like to have the burndown chart show tha actual history of the logged work, so your solution won't work here.

Comment: What if you just delete the work logged on the issues that overlaps with the initial instance of that sprint, then delete and recreate the sprint, and then re-log the time?

Comment: @DarthContinent I deleted the logged time from an issue, recreated the sprint, added some time logged with a date before today - no Time Spent was added to the sprint's burndown chart.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is not within the scope of questions appropriate for this site, as defined in [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Please also see: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) You may be able to get help on [another Stack Exchange site](http://stackexchange.com/sites#name).

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible as of now. If you backdate your sprint in JIRA Agile, all the stories added would start appearing as added after the sprint start and thus candidates of scope change. We also face this situation often.